# Use the actual value of String as a Formatted Value for TextBlock.Text

Tags: vb.net, string, variables, textbox

So basically I have this:

A WPF window with 1 Button (btn_Convert) and 2 TextBoxes (txtBox_StringValue and txtBox_Result).

In txtBox_StringValue I then paste in a formatted string value:

```
"This is a Header" & vbCrLf & "======================" & _
vbCrLf & "INFO" & vbCrLf & "======================"
```

Then when I click btn_Convert I would like the following to happen.

Code:

```
Dim tempStringValue = txtBox_StringValue.Text

txtBox_Results.Text = tempStringValue
```

However (obviously), when I do the above the Results TextBox just displays the string again:

```
"This is a Header" & vbCrLf & "======================" & _
vbCrLf & "INFO" & vbCrLf & "======================"
```

Instead of:

```
This is a Header
======================
INFO
```

So how do I get the value of the string and then strip the containing double-quotes so that the value when assigned acts like it was a variable value set in code, not just passing a string.

From the research I have done I am guessing that I need to use Reflection, however I am not familiar with the Reflection concept and don't know how to approach it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Reflection won't help you in this case.  It sounds like what you're talking about is dynamically interpreting some VB.NET source code and output the result of executing that code to another text box.  In that case you need to use the Code DOM classes to dynamically build an assembly in memory and execute it.